# 1st time being here for clarification please make a separate box for explanation of context of the question. Wink wink #context

Tags: context

Someone please message the curator or webmasters of this site to enable a context in box where someone can explain the scenario of the question they are asking, if we have the background information then we can better answer their question and waste less time or is that how the site makes money?

Comment: It probably won't happen. There is not "a curator" here; it is a whole organization, and the question answer format is well established by years of working a certain way. I'm making this a comment, because this is off topic on the main question site and could only be properly answered on [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/); please give some time to the [tour] when you can.

Comment: You can explain whatever you need to explain in the answer box. "context in box" is not a term. You might want to look at some questions and answers on this site to see how it works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's at worst a META question.

Comment: @Lambie: It's at ***best*** a META question! At ***worst***, it's the reason for [Don't. Migrate. Crap.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/153229)